# Precision and Scale in Hive Decimal Type

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqldatatypes

Lets say I have a column defined as decimal(18,8).

By definition, the field can have a total of 18 digits, but only 8 of which can be to the right of the decimal point.

My understanding was that you could have 18 digits to the left of the decimal point as long as there are no values to the right of the decimal point
e.g. values between -999999999999999999 and 999999999999999999.

But after loading data into hive, I am seeing that 18 whole digits with no decimal digits do not conform to the field's data type and are being loaded as NULL

What should be the expected behavior here?

Comment: In the database world a `decimal(p,s)` (or `numeric(p,s)`) is a **fixed-point** decimal -- with a few exceptions or edge cases. Hive implements `decimal` with `java.math.BigDecimal` and if you put your nose into OpenJDK source code you will find that `BigDecimal` is just a `BigInteger` plus the "position" as the **(fixed)** position of the decimal separator. End of story.

Comment: Caveat: **the Hive implementation has changed over time :((** -- in the beginning they had `decimal` with no scale/position, just like Oracle has `number(*)` -- but nowadays (since V0.12 I think) the `decimal` keyword alone is translated implicitly to `decimal(10,0)`